# Minecraft Java Plugin - Block locations are the same but it still doesnt work

Tags: java, minecraft

Anyone who can answer this problem. I am storing beacon location in a config. When a beacon is broken i am getting the location of the block that is breaking and checking if its equal to the one in my config. I dont know why its not working and I even did p.sendmessage and sent both values as a message and they're the excact same...

https://pastebin.com/Kd4eZyJc   Line 1181 is the block break event.

Block break event:

```
public HashMap<Integer, Block> beaconStore = new HashMap<>();
// WHEN PLAYER BREAKS BLOCK
@EventHandler
public void onBreak(BlockBreakEvent event){
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    Block block = event.getBlock();

    if (p.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.WOOD_HOE) {
        event.setCancelled(true);

        w = block.getLocation().getWorld().getName();
        x = block.getLocation().getX() + 0.500;
        y = block.getLocation().getY();
        z = block.getLocation().getZ() + 0.500;

        p.sendMessage("§6Saved coordinates for block. (World:" + w + " x:" + x + "," + " y:" + y + "," + " z:" + z + ")");

    }

    if (gameRunning == true) {
        boolean okBreak = false;
        for(Integer integer : BlockReset.keySet()){
              Block bl = BlockReset.get(integer);

              if (bl.equals(block)) {
                  okBreak = true;
              }
              else {

              }
        }

        Location blockLocation = block.getLocation();

        if (block.getType() == Material.BEACON) {
            okBreak = true;

            p.sendMessage(" " + blockLocation);

            World world = block.getWorld();



            double xyellowBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon1.x");
            double yyellowBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon1.y");
            double zyellowBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon1.z");
            Location yellowBeacon1Location = new Location(world, xyellowBeacon1, yyellowBeacon1, zyellowBeacon1);


            double xyellowBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon2.x");
            double yyellowBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon2.y");
            double zyellowBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon2.z");
            Location yellowBeacon2Location = new Location(world, xyellowBeacon2, yyellowBeacon2, zyellowBeacon2);

            double xyellowBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon3.x");
            double yyellowBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon3.y");
            double zyellowBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon3.z");
            Location yellowBeacon3Location = new Location(world, xyellowBeacon3, yyellowBeacon3, zyellowBeacon3);

            double xyellowBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon4.x");
            double yyellowBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon4.y");
            double zyellowBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("yellowbeacon4.z");
            Location yellowBeacon4Location = new Location(world, xyellowBeacon4, yyellowBeacon4, zyellowBeacon4);

            if (blockLocation == yellowBeacon1Location) {
                yellowbcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == yellowBeacon2Location) {
                yellowbcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == yellowBeacon3Location) {
                yellowbcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == yellowBeacon4Location) {
                yellowbcount--;
            }



            double xblueBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon1.x");
            double yblueBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon1.y");
            double zblueBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon1.z");
            Location blueBeacon1Location = new Location(world, xblueBeacon1, yblueBeacon1, zblueBeacon1);

            double xblueBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon2.x");
            double yblueBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon2.y");
            double zblueBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon2.z");
            Location blueBeacon2Location = new Location(world, xblueBeacon2, yblueBeacon2, zblueBeacon2);

            double xblueBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon3.x");
            double yblueBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon3.y");
            double zblueBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon3.z");
            Location blueBeacon3Location = new Location(world, xblueBeacon3, yblueBeacon3, zblueBeacon3);

            double xblueBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon4.x");
            double yblueBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon4.y");
            double zblueBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("bluebeacon4.z");
            Location blueBeacon4Location = new Location(world, xblueBeacon4, yblueBeacon4, zblueBeacon4);

            if (blockLocation == blueBeacon1Location) {
                bluebcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == blueBeacon2Location) {
                bluebcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == blueBeacon3Location) {
                bluebcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == blueBeacon4Location) {
                bluebcount--;
            }



            double xgreenBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon1.x");
            double ygreenBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon1.y");
            double zgreenBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon1.z");
            Location greenBeacon1Location = new Location(world, xgreenBeacon1, ygreenBeacon1, zgreenBeacon1);

            double xgreenBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon2.x");
            double ygreenBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon2.y");
            double zgreenBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon2.z");
            Location greenBeacon2Location = new Location(world, xgreenBeacon2, ygreenBeacon2, zgreenBeacon2);

            double xgreenBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon3.x");
            double ygreenBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon3.y");
            double zgreenBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon3.z");
            Location greenBeacon3Location = new Location(world, xgreenBeacon3, ygreenBeacon3, zgreenBeacon3);

            double xgreenBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon4.x");
            double ygreenBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon4.y");
            double zgreenBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("greenbeacon4.z");
            Location greenBeacon4Location = new Location(world, xgreenBeacon4, ygreenBeacon4, zgreenBeacon4);

            if (blockLocation == greenBeacon1Location) {
                greenbcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == greenBeacon2Location) {
                greenbcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == greenBeacon3Location) {
                greenbcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == greenBeacon4Location) {
                greenbcount--;
            }



            double xredBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon1.x");
            double yredBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon1.y");
            double zredBeacon1 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon1.z");
            Location redBeacon1Location = new Location(world, xredBeacon1, yredBeacon1, zredBeacon1);
            p.sendMessage(" " + redBeacon1Location);

            double xredBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon2.x");
            double yredBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon2.y");
            double zredBeacon2 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon2.z");
            Location redBeacon2Location = new Location(world, xredBeacon2, yredBeacon2, zredBeacon2);

            double xredBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon3.x");
            double yredBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon3.y");
            double zredBeacon3 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon3.z");
            Location redBeacon3Location = new Location(world, xredBeacon3, yredBeacon3, zredBeacon3);

            double xredBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon4.x");
            double yredBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon4.y");
            double zredBeacon4 = getConfig().getDouble("redbeacon4.z");
            Location redBeacon4Location = new Location(world, xredBeacon4, yredBeacon4, zredBeacon4);

            if (blockLocation == redBeacon1Location) {
                redbcount--;
                p.sendMessage("Okay!");
            }
            if (blockLocation == redBeacon2Location) {
                redbcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == redBeacon3Location) {
                redbcount--;
            }
            if (blockLocation == redBeacon4Location) {
                redbcount--;
            }
        }

        if (okBreak == true) {
            event.setCancelled(false);
        }
        else {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            p.sendMessage("§9§lPillars " + dot + " §7You can only break blocks placed by a player!");
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the beacon location in command:

```
if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("yellowbeacon1")) {
    getConfig().set("yellowbeacon1.world", w);
    getConfig().set("yellowbeacon1.x", x - 0.5);
    getConfig().set("yellowbeacon1.y", y);
    getConfig().set("yellowbeacon1.z", z - 0.5);
    saveConfig();

    p.sendMessage("§9§lPillars " + dot + " §7Successfully set §eyellow §5beacon1!");
}
```

^^ I do that for every beacon.

I hope you understand my problem.[image: Getting both locations]

Comment: Why are you storing/using block locations (integers) as doubles? Why aren't you using integers? Also, if you are using a version of Minecraft at or above 1.10, `BlockPos` is a thing that exists and will equate properly.

Comment: I store all as doubles so that I can change them however I want and more accurately. And I use 1.8.8 + I've already fixed the problem as I've commented

Comment: When are you ever going to need to know about a block at `X=15.2389074293874` and not `X=15`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be causing the issue you're getting, but when comparing `Location` class instances, use `equals` method instead of `==` as they're definitely not the same instance when you're creating one of the compared locations in the same method.

Not strongly related to your issue, but refactor your code a bit. If you have to copy-paste something, it marks as something that you could extract as method. So create method with signature `Location getLocation(World world, String beaconprefix)`, which fetches block location from config and creates it, significantly reducing the code length.

```
private Location getLocation(World world, String beaconPrefix) {
  double x = getConfig().getDouble(beaconPrefix + ".x");
  double y = getConfig().getDouble(beaconPrefix + ".y");
  double z = getConfig().getDouble(beaconPrefix + ".z");
  return new Location(world, x, y, z);
}
```